# Exporting a dynamically generated table to excel

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I have a Java application where reports are generated dynamically in the form of tables. I need to have a button on a webpage whereby clicking on it will export the table to Excel. The table has to be saved by the user at the client side. How can I achieve this functionality? Will Apache POI API be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **POI** successfully in the past, but it has its quirks. The best way I've used it is to have a "template" file with all your formatting, colouring, etc. in your server, and copy and populate it with your data when exporting.

But if your data is a simple column-separated table, and you don't worry yoo much about formatting and data types, why not exporting the data in **plain text? (CSV format)** This can be opened by Excel, and will be far more efficient in term of speed an memory usage when exporting your data.

It will also bit a lot simpler to generate, you can use your own POJO generator, which will be a lot easier to test.

Use POI only if your users expect dedicated date format or distinction between Integer / Text cells. Or if you need dynamically calculated cells (using formulas) If not, you can export everything as Strings, and Excel will find its way when opening the csv file.

Comment: I require a well formatted excel,but If it is easy to generate a csv I would like to try.can you direct me to some examples.

Comment: A quick Google search led me to this one: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/  but it's very easy, just write your data with a separator that never changes (usually ",", but you can have your user select the separator as well in your web page)

Comment: There's also [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/), which handles quoting/escaping/etc for you (which you'd otherwise have to do yourself)

Comment: @Guillaume I was unable to access the link you posted.do you have an alternative link.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime there's also a client-side library ([XLSX.js](http://blog.innovatejs.com/?tag=xlsx-js)) available. Might be handy when you use something like [datatables](http://datatables.net/) with client-side filtering and ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my colleagues have used POI api for exporting really big reports. I think now it is the best one.

Comment: do you have any code example where this functionality is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Also consider writing an HTML-format table (Excel can read that, too, including better formatting than CSV).

And, check out JExcelAPI, which I think is really easier to use than POI.